# Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView

Tags: android

This is my logcat, when I run my application:

```
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nyp.edu.waterbilltracker/nyp.edu.waterbilltracker.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3553)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3616)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:357)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at nyp.edu.waterbilltracker.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:22)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    ... 11 more
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    ... 26 more
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:835)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:712)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:149)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:167)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:154)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:745)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:353)
02-06 04:39:59.600: E/AndroidRuntime(32346):    ... 29 more
```

This is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/water" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/welcome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/billButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/opalbutton"
                    android:onClick="bill"
                    android:text="Water Bills"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteAdapter db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        Log.d("test", "test");
        Log.d("test", "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn());

        /**
        * Call this function whenever you want to check user login This will
        * redirect user to LoginActivity is he is not logged in
        * */
        session.checkLogin();
        Log.d("test", "test");

        // get user data from session
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

        // name
        String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

        Button bill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.billButton);
        TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);

        welcome.setText("Welcome, " + name + "!");

        db = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        db.openToWrite();

        if (db.MYDATABASE_TABLE3 != null) {

        }
        else {
            db.insert3("HDB 1-Room", "19.24");
            db.insert3("HDB 2-Room", "24.17");
            db.insert3("HDB 3-Room", "26.64");
            db.insert3("HDB 4-Room", "30.84");
            db.insert3("HDB 5-Room", "34.04");
            db.insert3("HDB Executive", "36.65");
            db.insert3("Apartment", "28.38");
            db.insert3("Terrace", "47.23");
            db.insert3("Semi-Detached", "52.60");
            db.insert3("Bungalow", "82.91");
        }

        bill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent("edu.nyp.billsActivity");

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.onCreate(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: where you have added this com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView in layout xml file ?

Comment: i just search through all my xml file, but i dont have com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView

Comment: unrelated, but you should never ever call Activity lifecycle methods manually (like that `this.onCreate(null)` call in your `onResume()`)

Comment: Are you trying to run your app on a device with an API level greater than 10? (i.e. Honeycomb or above)

Comment: @NasaGeek : The point you made about not calling life-cycle methods probably IS related. If you look at the stacktrace the actual cause of the problem is an OutOfMemoryError. Each time `onResume()` calls `this.onCreate(null)` a new instance of the layot file will be inflated as a result of the call to `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: @user3223267 : Remove `this.onCreate(null)` from your `onResume()` method. You should never do that and it's possibly the root of your problem.

Comment: Did you happen to find the source of the problem? I'm having the same one but only on some devices

Comment: Hey I have the exact same issue !! any luck?